# JavaScript Phaser game doesn't load?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm normally a python guy, and although JavaScript isn't completely new to me, the Phaser game library is. I'm trying to make an archery game with Phaser, and although my game file isn't complete, to my knowledge this file should at least load a background image. Could someone help me figure out why it isn't loading anything? I'm using VSCode's live server extension to load it, if that helps.

Index HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Game</Title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "phaser.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><script type="text/javascript" src="archery_game.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Game file

```
const game = new Phaser.game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update })

//Variables
let score = 0
let scoreText
let arrows
let player

function preload() {
    //Load and define our images
    game.load.image('archer', 'archer.png')
    game.load.image('sky', 'sky.png')
    game.load.image('ground', 'platform.png')
    game.load.image('target', 'archery_target.png')
}

function create() {
    //Implement physics
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.physics.ARCADE)

    //Add the sky sprite
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky')

    //Create the ground
    platforms = game.add.group()
    platforms.enableBody = true
    let ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 64, 'ground')
    ground.scale.setTo(2, 2)
}

function update() {
    //Update physics

}
```

Comment: Just a guess -- the double quotes in your constructor (`...Phaser.AUTO, '', ...`) are the parent element in the HTML to attach to per the Phaser docs. I wonder if, since you've left it as emptystring, it's not attaching to your HTML canvas.

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree I tried "game_index.html" instead of the empty quotes, still no result :/

Comment: It wouldn't be that, it'd have to something like.. you'd put html like `<div id="my-game"></div>` in your HTML and then set the parameter string to "my-game". According to the docs, that parameter should be `The DOM element into which this games canvas will be injected. Either a DOM ID (string) or the element itself.` So saying "game_index.html" wouldn't meet those requirements. Just a guess, though!

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree Tried that, still no luck. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Ah well, no idea then. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You need to capitalize the Game constructor:

```
const game = new Phaser.game(800, 600...
```

should be

```
const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600...
```

See
https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Game.html